# acos and cos with degrees not giving proper result

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, trigonometry

While I write code like below

```
NSLog(@"%f",acos(cos(1)));
```

it returns `1` as result but if I tried to obtain result from degree instead of radian then facing problem as below

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
NSLog(@"%f",acos(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1))));
```

then it returns `0.017453` instead of `1`.
If I write like below

```
NSLog(@"%f",acos(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1)))*180/M_PI);
```

then I'm getting proper `1` as result.
 But if I'll write like below

```
NSString *a1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1)))];
NSString *a2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",(acos([a1 doubleValue])*180/M_PI)];
NSLog(@"%f",[a2 doubleValue]);
```

then I'm getting `0.998999` as result.

 Then where the problem is?

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0.017453 is about how many radians are in one degree.

If you want your logging line to output `1`, you'll need to convert back to degrees.

```
#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle) ((angle) * 180.0 / M_PI)
NSLog(@"%f", RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(acos(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1)))));
```

Note that you may get a result like 0.9999, though, due to the limited accuracy of trigonometric functions, and of floats in general.

Comment: You're partway right. However, you should not convert the input to acos() between degrees and radians because it isn't an angle.

Comment: but how to apply this solution or issue whatever you say in calculator project?

Comment: @DuncanC, not sure what you mean. If you mean "you should not supply an angle as an argument to `acos`, I'm not. I'm supplying the return value of `cos` to `acos`.

Comment: Kevin, my mistake. I missed the fact that you had acos(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1))), so the degrees to radians conversion applies to the input to cosine, not the input to acos(). I retract my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Arc Cosine is the inverse of cosine.

Cosine takes an angle as input, and returns a value ranging from -1 to 1.
Arc Cosine (acos) takes a value from -1 to 1 as input, and returns an angle.

The input to acos() is not an angle, so you should not try to convert it between degrees and radians. The **result** is an angle. That's what you convert.

So you would write

x = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(acos(1)).

That would give you the angle at which the cosine is 1, expressed in degrees. (The value of acos(1) is 0, which is the same in degrees or radians.)

Better to use acos(0) as a test value. The cosine function = 0 at pi/2 (or 90 degrees.)

So

```
acos(0) == pi/2. (~1.5707)

RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(acos(0)) == 90.
```

### EDIT:

I see now that in your question you were taking acos(cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1)), which is correct.

However, you still need to convert the result of acos() to degrees if you want your answer in degrees, as described above. (And Kevin's answer is also correct. My mistake)

Note that cos(1) is a little strange, in both degrees and radians. That isn't going to give an even answer in either.

cos(0) = 1, cos(pi) = -1, cos(2pi) = 1. 
(or in degrees)
cos(180) = -1, and cos(360) = 1)

cos(1) in degrees is going to be an strange decimal value, and so will cos(1) in radians.

Comment: Who downvoted me? My answer is correct, and Kevin's answer is not correct. I didn't down vote Kevin's answer because it is partially correct. If you think I gave incorrect information, step up and say so.

Comment: I concur, I'll give one back :)

Comment: Actually, Kevin's answer is perfect. I didn't notice that the OP was using acos(cos(1)).